# xActiveDirectory has no cmdlets. Why?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've installed module http://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/xActiveDirectory/, imported it, but when I look at the module there seems to be nothing in it, least of all any cmdlets. Below is a transcript of what I did. Clearly I'm missing something but don't know what. Can anyone help?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> ipmo xActiveDirectory
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     0.0        chocolateyProfile                   {TabExpansion, Update-SessionEnvironment, refreshenv}
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Con...
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Binary     1.0.0.1    PackageManagement                   {Find-Package, Find-PackageProvider, Get-Package, Get-Pack...
Script     1.0.0.1    PowerShellGet                       {Find-Command, Find-DscResource, Find-Module, Find-RoleCap...
Script     1.2        PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadlineOption, Remove-PS...
Manifest   2.12.0.0   xActiveDirectory


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Module xActiveDirectory | fl


Name              : xActiveDirectory
Path              : C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\xActiveDirectory\2.12.0.0\xActiveDirectory.psd1
Description       : The xActiveDirectory module is originally part of the Windows PowerShell Desired State
                    Configuration (DSC) Resource Kit. This version has been modified for use in Azure. This module
                    contains the xADDomain, xADDomainController, xADUser, and xWaitForDomain resources. These DSC
                    Resources allow you to configure and manage Active Directory.

                    All of the resources in the DSC Resource Kit are provided AS IS, and are not supported through any
                    Microsoft standard support program or service.
ModuleType        : Manifest
Version           : 2.12.0.0
NestedModules     : {}
ExportedFunctions :
ExportedCmdlets   :
ExportedVariables :
ExportedAliases   :
```

Comment: Because it's entire reason for existing is as a DSC resource. It has to have a module container, but that doesn't have to export commands if the author doesn't want it to. Run `Get-DscResource`, that's what it exports and why it exists.

Comment: got it, thanks @Chris-dent

Answer (score 2):

`xActiveDirectory` is for use with Desired State Configuration. It includes DSC Resources, not cmdlets.

Try running this:

```
Get-DscResource -Module xActiveDirectory
```

Comment: Thanks, that clears up that mystery. I now need to go and learn more about DSC and what DSC resources are (I admit to having no clue). thx.

Comment: @jamiet [this is a good place to start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/overview?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), but if you want a book I recommend [Learning PowerShell DSC](https://www.amazon.com/Learning-PowerShell-DSC-James-Pogran/dp/1783980702). I did technical review for it, and I think it's a very comprehensive book with a good introduction for those not familiar with configuration management at all (by the way I get no compensation whatsoever for recommending this).